# how can I make a mex function printf while it's running?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, printf, mex

I have a mex file called in my MATLAB script. The mex function may take a while to run, so in order to prevent my code from "stopping there without any outputs", I put many `printf` statements in the mex file to output some running information about the data being processed.

But when I call the mex function, it doesn't `printf` anything and stays there during int's running.  Finally, after finishing its work, it will `printf` all the information I want -- NOT while it is running but *after* finishing. It's not what I want.

So I want to know how to make it not only `printf` what I want but also `printf` at the time I want it.

Comment: Note to close vote reviewers:  The question has been heavily edited and now is perfectly clear from the point of view of a MATLAB MEX user.  @zeakey: You should accept whatever answer worked for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `mexPrintf` is what you need.  But note that the command window does not forcibly flush the buffer it uses, often resulting in very long delays before your message is printed.  This happens if you begin heavy computations after calling `mexPrintf`.

A workaround is to use

```
mexEvalString("drawnow;")
```

after each call to `mexPrintf`.

If you find that unappealing, you can make a macro that calls both:

```
#define printfFnc(...) { mexPrintf(__VA_ARGS__); mexEvalString("drawnow;");}
```

This uses the variadic macro `__VA_ARGS__`.  It may not be a part of a standard, but seems to be in GCC and Visual C++.  Just call `printfFnc` like you would call `printf` (or `mexPrintf`).

Comment: that's the officially supported solution. There are always other ways :)

Comment: This does not work in R2016b. The output is still not visible till the function is finished. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3):

There is an undocumented C++ function that resides in `libmwservices.dll`. It apparently flushes the output buffer. Here is an example:

#### test_mex_print.cpp

```
#include "mex.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "libmwservices.lib")
extern bool ioFlush(void);

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        mexPrintf("%d\n", i);
        ioFlush();
    }
}
```

Simply compile it as: `mex -largeArrayDims test_mex_print.cpp`

Comment: Building on linux with gcc, append this to the "mex" command:   -lmwservices -lmwbuiltins

Comment: This is an amazing find and very useful! How did you find that function in the library?

Comment: @DarkCell `dumpbin.exe /DLL` can be used to list exported functions, or using a tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). There are similar tools for Linux (`objdump`, `nm`, `ldd`, etc.)

Comment: @Amro Yes I'm aware of such tools but there are so many included libraries in Matlab with so many symbols with partially very cryptic names, that it seems to be marvelous you found a function that does exactly what you wanted and you even found the correct data types without header files. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mexPrintf`](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/apiref/mexprintf.html)

```
*
* mex equivalent to MATLAB's "disp" function
*/
extern int mexPrintf(const char *fmt, /* printf style format */
                     ... /* any additional arguments */);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as the OP, where mexPrintf() would not print any output until the mex file finished running. Moreover, mexEvalString("drawnow;"); didn't seem to fix the problem, or at least it didn't with my setup (MATLAB2015b with 64 bit MinGW compiler of C++11 MEX code).

However, using mexEvalString("pause(.001);"); after mexPrintf() did fix it. It took me some trial-and-error to figure out, so I hope this might be useful for future reference.

TLDR: use mexEvalString("pause(.001);");

Answer (score -1):

printf prints to stdout which *isnt* the matlab screen. (It is hidden by default and collected/displayed at the end)

Try mexprintf():

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/apiref/mexprintf.html

> In a C MEX-file, you must call mexPrintf instead of printf to display a string.

```
C Syntax

#include "mex.h"
int mexPrintf(const char *message, ...);

Arguments

message
String to display. In C, the string can include conversion specifications, used by the ANSI® C printf function.

...
In C, any arguments used in the message. Each argument must have a corresponding conversion specification.

Returns
Number of characters printed including characters specified with backslash codes, such as \n and \b.
```

Comment: actually if you look in `mex.h`, the header file has `#define printf mexPrintf` just in case... So it makes no difference.