# Clear MATLAB command window from mex function

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have a `for` loop in a `mexFunction`, which displays some information at every iteration. Consider this simple code, which will print 100 lines in the MATLAB command window and update at every iteration:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <time.h>       

using namespace std;

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
    int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int numiters = 100;
    /* initialize random seed: */
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int iter = 1; iter <= numiters; ++iter)
    {
        int rand_num = rand() % 100 + 1;

        /* Print info in matlab */
        std::ostringstream buffer;
        buffer << "iter = " << iter << " of " << numiters << 
            ". random number = " << rand_num << endl;

        /* need something similar to clc here */
        mexPrintf("%s", buffer.str().c_str());
    }
    return;
}
```

At every iteration I wish to clear MATLAB's command window before calling `mexPrintf()`.

I am aware that I can use [`mexCallMATLAB`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html), to invoke MATLAB's `clc`, but I am not sure if invoking MATLAB at every iteration is very efficient, hence I need a solution native to C++.

Comment: *"I am not sure if invoking MATLAB at every iteration is very efficient"* It may be, you are invoking it by doing `mexPrintf()` anyway. I suggest you try and time it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri. Fair point. I inserted `mexCallMATLAB(0, NULL, 0, NULL, "clc");` before `mexPrintf()` with no effect. Not sure why.

Comment: I realized why it wasn't working. I was missing using `ioFlush()`. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption about `mexCallMATLAB` being inefficient was wrong, thanks to @Ander Biguri for the heads up. I used the following test code to compare times with and without `mexCallMATLAB`.

---

## TL;DR - TIMING RESULTS

- With `mexCallMATLAB(0, NULL, 0, NULL, "clc");`: `mean time per iteration = 0.1016885 sec`
- Without `mexCallMATLAB(0, NULL, 0, NULL, "clc");`: `mean time per iteration = 0.0978730 sec`

---

## DETAILS

### Test Bench Summary

- Create a vector with 1 million random integers and take the mean.
- Repeat for 500 iterations.
- Compute time required for each iteration and save in vector.
- Average iteration times to get mean time per iteration.

### Code

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
extern bool ioFlush(void);

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
    int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int numiters = 500;
    /* initialize random seed: */
    srand(time(NULL));

    std::vector<double> all_times(numiters);

    for (int iter = 1; iter <= numiters; ++iter)
    {
        /* tic */
        clock_t begin = clock();

        std::vector<int> rand_vec;

        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
            rand_vec.push_back( rand() % 100 + 1 );

        double vec_mean = 0.0;
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < rand_vec.size(); ++i)
            vec_mean += rand_vec[i];

        vec_mean /= rand_vec.size();

        /* clear screen */
        mexCallMATLAB(0, NULL, 0, NULL, "clc");

        /* toc */
        double time_elapsed = double(clock() - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        /* Print data in matlab */
        std::ostringstream buffer;
        buffer << "iter " << iter << " of " << numiters << 
                ". random vector mean = " << vec_mean << 
                ". in " << time_elapsed << "s" << endl;

        mexPrintf("%s", buffer.str().c_str());
        ioFlush();

        all_times[iter] = time_elapsed;
    }

    double avg_time = 0.0;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < all_times.size(); ++i)
        avg_time += all_times[i];

    avg_time /= all_times.size();
    mexPrintf("\navg time per iter = %3.7f\n", avg_time);

    return;
}
```

Note the use of `ioFlush()` which is an undocumented function needed to update command window at every iteration. See more details about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271154/how-can-i-make-a-mex-function-printf-while-its-running/26271557).

### To Compile

- On Windows using Visual Studio: Add `#pragma comment(lib, "libmwservices.lib")` in source file.
- On Ubuntu using gcc: Compile using `mex yourFile.cpp -lmwservices`

Comment: Great job, nice answer.