# Matlab mex-function mexPrintf does not print immediately

Tags: printf, simulink, mex

This question hass been asked several times, but no solution does work for me. I want to use printf (or mexPrintf / ssPrintf) in an Matlab-mex file (called in a simulink s-function). The problem here is, that the output is only display after the function is finished, and I never get an instant message, while the function is running. I am using R2016b. I tried several things, like for example:

```
#define printf(...) { mexPrintf(__VA_ARGS__); mexEvalString("drawnow;"); mexEvalString("pause(0.01);"); }
```

I also tried the following solutions, but neither works:

[how can I make a mex function printf while it's running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271154/how-can-i-make-a-mex-function-printf-while-its-running)

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/255615-why-are-mex-file-output-messages-using-mexprintf-mexevalstring-drawnow-not-printed-immediatel

Is there a way to get this working, or is this simply not possible in this release? Thanks.

Comment: Regarding this solution: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/255615-why-are-mex-file-output-messages-using-mexprintf-mexevalstring-drawnow-not-printed-immediatel#answer_215636 What does happen when you run it?

Comment: Actually I started to compile my model with grt.tlc into an exe. Running this, I get an immidiate output in the console-window. This works well, so I do not bother any more with getting this to work in simulink/matlab.